# Transform dataframe such that numeric columns are standardised and categorical columns are encoded

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe:

```
{'Height': {0: 175, 1: 160, 2: 150, 3: 180, 4: 170, 5: 175, 6: 165},
'Gender': {0: 'Male',1: 'Female',2: 'Female',3: 'Male',4: 'Male',5: 'Male',6: 'Male'},
'Age': {0: 1.0, 1: 2.0, 2: 8.0, 3: 4.0, 4: 5.0, 5: 2.0, 6: 9.0}}
```

I tried the following loop to give me the dataframe with the numeric columns standardised and the categorical columns encoded:

```
for i in df:
    if is_numeric_dtype(df[i]):
        df[i]=StandardScaler(with_mean=0,with_std=1).fit_transform(df[i])
    else:
        df[i]=LabelEncoder().fit_transform(df[i])
```

This gives an error about having to reshape data for a single feature:

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Is there a way to transform the dataframe with different rule applied to numerical and categorical columns?  Is there a way of doing it without a for loop?

In this example I have three columns, but sometimes I may have 100 columns so I don't want to have to alter each column individually

Comment: Please post the complete error message that you receive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder, StandardScaler

ord_enc = OrdinalEncoder()
std_enc = StandardScaler()

type_n = 'float64'
type_o = 'object'


dtypes = df.dtypes.to_dict()

for col_nam, typ in dtypes.items():
    if (typ == type_o):
        df[col_nam] = ord_enc.fit_transform(df[[col_nam]])
    if (typ == type_n):
        df[col_nam] = std_enc.fit_transform(df[[col_nam]])
```

Comment: I don't want to have to do it to each column individually

Comment: You should edit your question then

Comment: I have edited the answer, now works with 100 columns

Answer (score 0):

Do exactly as the error message says - reshape the input to `StandardScaler`

```
df['Height2'] = StandardScaler(with_mean=0, with_std=1).fit_transform(df['Height'].values.reshape(-1,1))
```